# Unable to create realtime database on firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm going through a Flutter tutorial using a very simple firebase realtime database. Everything was working fine, then suddenly I get an error through flutter:

Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61

From what I found, this error meant that there was something wrong with the host I was trying to connect to (something wrong with my firebase). When I visited firebase, the database was suddenly empty.

I deleted the firebase project and opened multiple new projects on multiple new google accounts,  but each time I tried to set up the Realtime Database on firebase I get "An error has occurred: null"

[Error creating realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYeq7.png)

I have no idea what the problem is. I haven't found anything helpful online about this problem. I was hoping someone on here has experienced this or knows what to do?

(p.s. I don't think its an issue with exceeding my unpaid firebase plan. They say you're allowed a database for each project you create.)

Comment: If you're having problems working with the Firebase console, you should contact Firebase support directly for assistance. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1):

Connection refused is normally a rule related problem.
Try going into the locked mode and manually rewrite the rules and make them true and true, for both read and write.

Comment: Yeah thing is firebase isn't letting me create any type of database, so I cant edit the rules. I contacted their support though to see what they have to say.  Thanks for the help.